# Difference between pandas.date_range and dataframe.index

Tags: python, pandas, difference, date-range

Using Python prompt on Linux, I read data from a csv file with pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None, index_col=5)
```

and I obtain

```
>>> my_data.index
Index([u'2018.09.20 19:00', u'2018.09.20 19:15', u'2018.09.20 19:30',
       u'2018.09.20 19:45', u'2018.09.20 20:00', u'2018.09.20 20:15',
       u'2018.09.20 20:30', u'2018.09.20 20:45', u'2018.09.20 21:00',
       u'2018.09.20 21:15', u'2018.09.20 21:30', u'2018.09.20 21:45',
       u'2018.09.20 22:00', u'2018.09.20 22:15', u'2018.09.20 22:30',
       u'2018.09.20 22:45', u'2018.09.20 23:00', u'2018.09.20 23:15',
       u'2018.09.20 23:30', u'2018.09.20 23:45'],
      dtype='object', name=5)
```

which are all the date and time from **2018.09.20 19:00** to **2018.09.20 23:45** with a frequence of 15 minutes.

Now, I would like to check for missing date and time.

If I use the same interval, it's fine:

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018.09.20 19:00', end = '2018.09.20 23:45', freq = '15min').difference(my_data.index)
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15T')
```

If I shift the "start" in pd.data_range to **2018.09.20 20:00**, I obtain

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018.09.20 20:00', end = '2018.09.20 23:45', freq = '15min').difference(my_data.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-20 20:00:00', '2018-09-20 20:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 20:30:00', '2018-09-20 20:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 21:00:00', '2018-09-20 21:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 21:30:00', '2018-09-20 21:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 22:00:00', '2018-09-20 22:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 22:30:00', '2018-09-20 22:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 23:00:00', '2018-09-20 23:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 23:30:00', '2018-09-20 23:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

The same odd result is obtained if I shift the "start" to **2018.09.20 18:00**

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018.09.20 18:00', end = '2018.09.20 23:45', freq = '15min').difference(my_data.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-20 18:00:00', '2018-09-20 18:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 18:30:00', '2018-09-20 18:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 19:00:00', '2018-09-20 19:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 19:30:00', '2018-09-20 19:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 20:00:00', '2018-09-20 20:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 20:30:00', '2018-09-20 20:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 21:00:00', '2018-09-20 21:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 21:30:00', '2018-09-20 21:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 22:00:00', '2018-09-20 22:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 22:30:00', '2018-09-20 22:45:00',
               '2018-09-20 23:00:00', '2018-09-20 23:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 23:30:00', '2018-09-20 23:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Not sure if this behaviour is due to dtype='object' in my_data.index, I tried to convert to a datetime and it seems to work fine. In fact

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018.09.20 20:00', end = '2018.09.20 23:45', freq = '15min').difference(pd.to_datetime(my_data.index))
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018.09.20 18:00', end = '2018.09.20 23:45', freq = '15min').difference(pd.to_datetime(my_data.index))
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-20 18:00:00', '2018-09-20 18:15:00',
               '2018-09-20 18:30:00', '2018-09-20 18:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**My questions**

1. Is it possible that the first "odd" behaviour is due to the fact that I have dtype='object' in my_data.index?
2. Is it correct to use

```
pd.to_datetime
```

to solve this problem?

3. Why does the first case (the one with the same interval) work fine even if I do not use pd.to_datetime?

Comment: Yes, pd.to_datetime your index first.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks. What about the question number 3? Does it happen by chance that it works?

Comment: I suspect comparison needs to be like dtypes.